# How does make Android phone with Bluetooth Low Energy to connect two devices at same type?

Tags: android

I have two BLE devices(not android phone) and i use android phone to connect them.

In common, if the android phone has connected with first BLEdevice.
Then i will connect to second device, the second device doesn't connect the phone.

How to make two devices connect with android phone at same time?

(Simpley, 1 android phone connect to 2 ble device at same time)

Use BluetoothGatt?
User BluetoothSocket?